# Openai Gym Setup Problem Module Not Found

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, openai-gym

I'm trying to use Open AI's anytrading environment, but I'm running into this issue during setup. Has anyone come across this before?

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym.wrappers.order_enforcing'

```
import gym
import gym_anytrading

from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import VecFrameStack, DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3 import A2C

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

env = gym.make('stocks-v0')
```